# Threads on GAE with Python 2.7 throws "FrontendsNotSupported" error

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I migrated my app on GAE from Python 2.5 to Python 2.7.

Python 2.7 allow threading, and I'm trying to create a thread for send an e-mail in background. Here the thread:

```
from google.appengine.api import background_thread
from django.core.mail import send_mail

subject = 'Hello!'
msg = '\n \n Hello World!'
sender = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
to = 'xx@xx.com'

t = background_thread.BackgroundThread(target=send_mail, args=[subject, msg, sender, to])
t.start()
```

It should works on GAE, but after I upload the app and try to execute it, appears the following error:

```
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: FrontendsNotSupported
Exception Location: /python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/background_thread/background_thread.py in start_new_background_thread, line 84
Python Executable:  /python27_runtime/python27_dist/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Does anybody know why appear this error?

---

**CODE USING Normal Threads:**

```
from threading import Thread
from django.core.mail import send_mail

subject = 'Hello!'
msg = '\n \n Hello World!'
sender = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
to = 'xx@xx.com

t = Thread(target=send_mail, args=[subject, msg, sender, to], kwargs={'fail_silently': False})
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only run background threads on `backend` instances.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/

> Backends are special App Engine instances that have no request deadlines, higher memory and CPU limits, and persistent state across requests. They are started automatically by App Engine and can run continously for long periods. Each backend instance has a unique URL to use for requests, and you can load-balance requests across multiple instances.

You can use normal threads (threading) on frontend instances, but you can only use `backgroundthread` on backends.

> Code running on a backend can start a background thread, a thread that can "outlive" the request that spawns it. They allow backend instances to perform arbitrary periodic or scheduled tasks or to continue working in the background after a request has returned to the user.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#background_threads

It actually says in the error `FrontendsNotSupported` so front ends are not supported for this. You can use "normal" python thread syntax on a front end however.

Comment: Thank you @Paul-c, I was not aware about that difference. Even so, I wrote the same code I had before the migration from Python 2.5 to Python 2.7, but it is not working now. It doesn't throw any error, but it's not sending any e-mail. Do you know what could happen? (I edited my question with the code)

Comment: Sorry no. I don't do email in GAE yet.

Comment: Background threads can also be used on modules, not just backends(which are deprecated now anyways, since March 2013).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than incur the cost of a backend instance, you can use a TaskQueue on a normal instance instead.  Since you're only writing an email, it doesn't seem like you need the horsepower and time that a backend instance provides:

Per https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/

> With the Task Queue API, applications can perform work outside of a
>   user request, initiated by a user request. If an app needs to execute
>   some background work, it can use the Task Queue API to organize that
>   work into small, discrete units, called tasks. The app adds tasks to
>   task queues to be executed later.

Per https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/ you get a 10 minute deadline for TaskQueue on a normal FREE instance.

Here is some code:

**handlers.py**

```
    from google.appengine.ext import webapp
    from google.appengine.api import mail

    class YourMail(webapp.RequestHandler):

      def post(self):
        body_string = self.request.get("body_string")
        mail.send_mail(
          sender="you@your-domain.appengine.com",
          to="abc@abc.com",
          subject="Your subject",
          body=body_string)
```

Register the handler:
**main.py**

```
    #Add the handler to your WSGIApplication declaration.
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
      ('/example',     yourcode.AnotherModule),
      #mail handler
      ('/send_mail',   handlers.YourMail),
      ], debug=True)
```

**To call**

```
    from google.appengine.api.labs import taskqueue

    taskqueue.add(url="/send_mail", params={
      'body_string': "your body",
    })
```

Comment: +1, though this is not the answer of the question, but this is actually a better solution for the problem questioner is facing.